# Cant open another app by my app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an error when i run my app:

```
E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
 Reading a NULL string not supported here.
D/gift-manager: getGiftPara pkg(com.example.myhomie,260,), ret=-22
I/libMEOW_gift: ctx:0xb40000786ccfd928, ARC not Enabled.
E/libEGL: Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.so
I/chatty: uid=10300(com.example.myhomie) RenderThread identical 62 lines
E/libEGL: Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.so
E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
```

Mycode:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cctv);
    start = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = 
            getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome");
            startActivity(intent);
         }
        });
       }
```

Can anyone help me where is the error? Thanks you so much

Comment: "I have an error when i run my app" -- none of those appear to be from your app.

Comment: In my phone, I find a package name google browser: com.android.chrome. But i can run my app

Answer (score 1):

The error is: `E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.`
Put your intent code into try-catch. Also check the intent returned by `getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome");`

Comment: intent returned NULL. So what should i do next?

Comment: So, the problem is clear. You are trying to start an activity with the reference of a null intent. `getLaunchIntentForPackage` return null intent means either chrome is not installed/ not a valid package id/ chrome is disabled.

Comment: But when I check the package name of google chrome , it is still com. android.chrome, and I'm also running chrome. I dont know why intent returned null

Comment: Then debug the `getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome")` method and check the logic, why it's returning `null`. There must be a valid reason.